# How to print variables in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to use cmake to build my project, my CMakeLists.txt is very simple:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

 project(YuvParallelProcess)

 message("$(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)")

 include_directories($(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)/inc)
 link_directories($(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)/lib/libyuv)

 add_executable(YuvParallelProcess  $(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)/src/main.cpp)

 target_link_libraries(YuvParallelProcess  libyuv.a)
```

my project files are organized as follows:

```
 YuvParallelProcess
                      build
                      data
                      inc
                      lib
                      src
                      CMakeLists.txt
```

when I run `cmake ..` in `build` directory, the shell prints:

```
$(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    $(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)/src/main.cpp


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_executable):
  No SOURCES given to target: YuvParallelProcess
```

I don't know why the shell just prints `$(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)` other than the value of `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`
How can I print the value of `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`
By the way, I can't figure out why cmake failed to compile my project

Comment: IN addition to the answer below: You don't need to use absolute paths in most of these cases and if you do it's preferrable to use `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, since this refers to the directory containing the current `CMakeLists.txt` file regardless of whether there's a `project()` command or not; in more complex projects you may leave out this command in a subdirectory. Furthermore I recommend restricting the include/link directory definitions to where they are needed and use `target_include_directories`/`target_link_directories`

Answer (score 45):

Cmake uses curly braces for getting values of variables:

```
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
```

I suggest to dump messages like below to not skip empty messages.

```
message(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR="${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

Cmake failed to configure your project because it did not recognise variables in parentheses and considered `$(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)` to be a string literal as is.

There is CMakePrintHelpers Cmake module for dumping variables exactly like above.

```
include(CMakePrintHelpers)
cmake_print_variables(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)
```

Answer (score 24):

Instead of using `message`, you can also use `cmake_print_variables` to display variables.
in this case, you must include `CMakePrintHelpers`

```
include(CMakePrintHelpers)

cmake_print_variables(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)
```

The ouput will be :

```
-- PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR="path/to/your/project"
```

With `cmake_print_variables` you can also display several variables, like this:

```
cmake_print_variables(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR ANOTHER_VARIABLE)
```

The ouput will be :

```
-- PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR="path/to/your/project" ; ANOTHER_VARIABLE="other variable"
```